# Is $x^{1/3}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus

Is the cube root of $x$: $x^{1/3}$, a continuous function? I thought $x$ cannot be negative. Therefore, the domain is the all real numbers greater than zero.

I have a continuity problem that asks if the following is continuous:
$$(2x - 1)^{1/3}.$$

The solution states that is a composite of two functions that are continuous, $x^{1/3}$ and $2x - 1$. And so, the result is continuous.

Thank you.

Comment: The principal square root of a negative number is nonreal.  The [principal cube root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root) of a negative number however is real.  $\sqrt[3]{-8}$ for instance is $-2$, noting that $(-2)\times (-2)\times (-2)=-8$

Comment: Strictly speaking, the third root is defined for negative numbers:  $(-8)^{1/3}= -2$.  However, you are right that, in order to be able to use the 'laws of exponents', the **function** $f(x)= x^{1/3}$ has domain non-negative numbers.  However, it does *not* then follow that " the domain is the all real numbers greater than zero.".  The domain is "all real numbers greater than **or equal to** zero.  When a function is defined on such an interval, in order to be continuous at boundary points, the limit only has to be taken through points in the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any discontinuous point in these functions, so the domain of both $$x^{\frac13}$$ and $$(2x-1)^{\frac13}$$ is $R$.

Whenever we have a $\sqrt{}$  functions with noneven roots, we check function in sqrt. You could check dominator functions, $\tan$, $\log$, and so on.